# Filter bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-filters

I'm using filtered questions from https://stackexchange.com/filters/. Is it possible to make a filter that lists all bounty questions from a list of sites? If so, is it also possible to filter only the bounties with, let's say, 100+ rep?

If not, can we have such a filter? It would allow people to browse featured questions from multiple sites at once.

Comment: Apparently you can't (because it only allowed filtering by tag), but I'm not an expert.